# Compilation error when dynamically setting property of user control inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In a C# Webforms website (not web application), I have the following set up:

A page, which includes Step.ascx which includes an `asp:Repeater`.

The repeater in Step.ascx displays all sections (`Section.ascx`) within this step.

`SectionInfoProvider.GetSections(1).ToList()` returns a list of `SectionInfo`, which is a class several properties including `DisplayName` as string.

I'm getting a compilation error (The type or namespace name could not be found) when trying to dynamically set the `SectionInfo` property of the `Section` user control into the repeater in Step.ascx.cs. I've tried using the partial class name of the user control, and `UserControl`, but neither work.

I'm also trying to create a collection of `SectionControls` because I want to use that for something else on the page too.

What am I doing wrong here?

Step.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/Step.ascx.cs" Inherits="Custom_Step" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Section" Src="~/Section.ascx" %>

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptSections" OnItemDataBound="rptSections_OnItemDataBound" EnableViewState="True">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <uc:Section runat="server" ID="Section" EnableViewState="True"/>            
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Step.ascx.cs

```
public partial class Custom_Step : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public IEnumerable<SectionInfo> Sections { get; set; }
    private IEnumerable<???> SectionControls { get; set; } <-- What should ??? be?

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Sections = SectionInfoProvider.GetSections(1).ToList();

        rptSections.DataSource = Sections;
        rptSections.DataBind();    
    }

    protected void rptSections_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var info = (SectionInfo)e.Item.DataItem;
        var ctrl = (???)e.Item.FindControl("Section");  <-- What should ??? be?
        ctrl.SectionInfo = info;

        if (SectionControls == null) SectionControls = new List<???>();  <-- What should ??? be?
        ((List<???>)SectionControls).Add(ctrl); <-- What should ??? be?
    }    
}
```

Section.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/Section.ascx.cs" Inherits="Custom_Section " %>

<h3><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litSectionHeading" /></h3>
```

Section.ascx.cs:

```
public partial class Custom_Section : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public SectionInfo SectionInfo { get; set; }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        litSectionHeading.Text = SectionInfo.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try `var ctrl = e.Item.FindControl<Custom_Section>("Section");` or `var ctrl = (Custom_Section)e.Item.FindControl("Section");` I get the message 'The type or namespace 'Custom_Section' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). How do I correctly reference the 'type' of the `Custom_Section` user control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need a typecast and an if.

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {`
...
var ctrl = e.Item.FindControl<Custom_Section>("Section");`
or
var ctrl = (Section)e.Item.FindControl("Section");
...
}
```

Is that something you already tried?

Creating the dynamic controls can be done but that's a separate question.

Comment: When I try `var ctrl = e.Item.FindControl<Custom_Section>("Section");` or `var ctrl = (Section)e.Item.FindControl("Section");` I get the message 'The type or namespace 'Custom_Section' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: Can only think the repeater is wrapped in a namespace and the Custom_Section isn't.  Make sure the `namespace <namespace_name>` are the same in all your files.

Comment: As strange as this sounds, I ended up closing VS, rebooting, commenting out those lines that didn't compile, fully compiling, rebooting again and then adding the lines back in. With your example using `Custom_Section` it works as expected. Thank you Salik.